# ng table do not filter empty string in strict comparison

Tags: angularjs, filter, string, ngtable

I am using Ng-Table to show a list of items with 3 columns: Name, Rack, Group.

I wanted to apply 'strict comparison' to those columns, so what I did was:

```
  self.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    // This count: 2 can be ignored as we change it in every request.
    count: 50,
  }, {
    counts: [],
    total: 100,
    getData: function ($defer, params) {

      var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(self.data, params.filter(), true) : self.data;
      var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : self.data;

      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
  });
```

You can assume that `self.data` contains all my data and `var self = this;` in my controller.

The problem with the afore mentioned code, is that when you **erase** the filter string in one of the columns, the `$filter('filter')(self.data, params.filter(), true)` returns no result.

I found that, when you **erase** on column (lets say Name column), params.filter() will contain an object like this: {'name': ""} which is passing to the `$filter('filter')` and the filter is trying to match only empty strings!!

I tried to override this by adding the following code:

```
   getData: function ($defer, params) {
      // When the user deletes the search text, this object keeps a variable with an empty string. The
      // strict comparator will accept only empty strings. To overcome this problem we delete the property
      for (var propt in params.filter()) {
        if (params.filter()[propt] === '') {
          delete params.filter()[propt];
        }
      }

      var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(self.data, params.filter()) : self.data;
      var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : self.data;

      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
```

My problem is that is not an *elegant* solution, and this code is looping for all search columns to see if one of them is an empty string. Can I do something faster? That can find exactly which column is empty and delete the property? Something more *elegant* and less hacky?

Answer (score 1):

I have a little correction for your solution, because, in case of using your code, filter after input parameter, erase, input **do not work**. For getting filtered data user have to input parameter again. That's why I copied  params.filter() to another variable and worked whit it.

```
getData: function ($defer, params) {

  var customFilter = angular.copy(params.filter());

  for (var propt in customFilter) {
   if (customFilter[propt] === '') {
         delete customFilter[propt];
      }
   }
orderedData = customFilter ? $filter('filter')(orderedData, customFilter, true) : orderedData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this problem has since been solved by including the 'trim' parameter to params.filter():

```
getData: function(params) {
  var myData = /* ... */
  var filteredData = (params.filter(true) ? 
     $filter('filter')(myData, params.filter(true) : 
     myData);
  return filteredData;
}
```

Per the [ngTable API documentation](http://ng-table.com/api-docs/classes/ngtableparams.html#filter):

> trim: boolean
>
> [Optional] supply true to return the current filter minus any insignificant values (null,  undefined and empty string)